# Which font folder does VSCode use in Linux?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, fonts

I would like to install a font to use in VS Code, so I would like to know where VS Code searches for fonts on Linux. Is it `/usr/share/fonts/`? Because it doesn't seem like it recognizes all of my fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/usr/share/fonts` is indeed the folder you are looking for in Linux.

Here is a link that might help you with the recognition of your fonts:

https://superuser.com/questions/1356517/use-a-font-in-vscode